# How to upgrade Eclipse to SimRel version

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-orion

I have Eclipse version **Oxygen** 2 and I'd like to upgrade to the latest **SimRel** version instead of doing  fresh install because I have many configurations etc. I've tried to update using `Install/Update` tab with repository link `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/simrel` like in the previous versions but this time the repository link is incorrect, I've also tried other links but still no success. Is the repository stored in other place?

Is update from **Oxygen** to **SimRel** supported? If yes then how can I do it?

Comment: Orion is not a new Eclipse version, rather an Open Source project. The newest version of Eclipse is Eclipse SimRel. Maybe try this in the link instead?

Comment: @JPadley You're right, I've corrected the question because I have the same problem with SimRel.

Comment: @JPadley The release name is 'SimRel 2018-09', there will be a 'SimRel 2018-12', 'SimRel 2019-03' and so on so please use the full name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the update site [`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/) to upgrade to the latest release (which is currently 2018-09).

See: [Eclipse Wiki - FAQ How do I upgrade Eclipse IDE? - Always enable major upgrades](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades)